# Find position of object by Key in json file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Is there anyway i can find the position of object by its key in Json file. I tried with the collection module but seems not to work with data from the json file even though its dictionary

```
reda.json file

[{"carl": "33"}, {"break": "55"}, {"user": "heake"}, ]
```

```
import json
import collections

json_data = json.load(open('reda.json'))
if type(json_data) is dict:
    json_data = [json_data]

d = collections.OrderedDict((json_data))
h = tuple(d.keys()).index('break')
print(h)
```

Also tried this

```
j = 'break'
for i in json_data:
    if j in i:
      print(j.index('break'))

Result is 0
``
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` to generate indices for a sequence:

```
json_data = [{"carl": "33"}, {"break": "55"}, {"user": "heake"}]
key = 'break'
for index, record in enumerate(json_data):
    if key in record:
        print(index)
```

This outputs: `1`

Answer (score 0):

You don't require `collections` for this. Simply use list comprehension to generate a list and then get the index.

Here's my code:

```
import json

json_data = json.load(open('reda.json'))
json_key_index = [key for key in json_data]
print(json_key_index.index("break"))
```

Also, looking at your `reda.json` the format doesn't seem pretty well-versed. I recommend changing the `reda.json` to:

```
{
    "carl": "33", 
    "break": "55", 
    "user": "heake"
}
```